# Mongoose MissingSchemaError happening inconsistently with Mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In `users.spec.js` I have this and it works fine:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var assert = require('assert');
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('../../app.js');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var Local = mongoose.model('Local');
var agent = request.agent(app);
var invalidId = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
```

In `app.js` I have:

```
mongoose.connect(dbUrl);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Problem connecting to database.'));
db.once('open', function onDbConnect() {
  console.log('Connected to ' + dbUrl + ' database...');
  // create models
  require('./api/users/user.model.js');
```

And in `user.model.js` I have:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var Local = mongoose.model('Local', localSchema);
```

So when `users.spec.js` is run, it first creates the models, and then I can reference them by `mongoose.model('User')` and `mongoose.model('Local')`.

However, in `auth.spec.js`, I'm doing the same thing, and it's not working:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var assert = require('assert');
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('../../app.js');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var Local = mongoose.model('Local');
var agent = request.agent(app);
```

Output:

```
/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:332
      throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
            ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model (/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:332:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/server/api/auth/auth.spec.js:5:21)
```

Why is this? I'm running the tests separately: `mocha server/api/auth` and `mocha server/api/users`, so they shouldn't be interfering with one another.

Full code [here](https://github.com/adamzerner/mean-starter/tree/6597ab8392960ee6405df1a0c40d6baa0e16f003).

Note: this works, but I'd prefer not to use it. Or at least I'd like to understand what the problem is and why this works.

```
// :( https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1251
// it isn't exactly my issue, but the recommendation on the bottom works
try {
  var User = mongoose.model('User');
  var Local = mongoose.model('Local');
}
catch(e) { 
  var schemas = require('../users/user.model.js');
  var User = mongoose.model('User', schemas.UserSchema);
  var Local = mongoose.model('Local', schemas.LocalSchema);
}
```